# Is there a way to pass values with a button click in c#

Tags: c#, winforms, button, user-input

I have a simple program that uses a text file as it's primary data entry and I have to create a windows forms application that will allow the user to manipulate with that data. I created a few buttons that should allow us to delete, edit, add and show us the data in the .txt file. I have figured out how to write out the data from that table on a button click, but i cannot seem to figure out how to save data from a user's input.

```
private void input_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
        string brand;
        int power, year;
        double price;

        string message, title, defaultValue;
        message = "Input the brand of a tractor ";
        title = "Insert a new Tractor";
        defaultValue = "John Deere";

        brand= Interaction.InputBox(message, title, defaultValue, 100, 100);

        defaultValue = "100";
        message = "input Power";
        power= Convert.ToInt32(Interaction.InputBox(message, title, defaultValue, 100, 100));

        defaultValue = "100000";
        message = "Input price";
        cena = Convert.ToDouble(Interaction.InputBox(message, title, defaultValue, 100, 100));

        defaultValue = "2020";
        message = "input Year";
        year= Convert.ToInt32(Interaction.InputBox(message, title, defaultValue, 100, 100));


        Array.Resize(ref listTraktor, listTraktor.Length+1);
        listTraktor[listTraktor.Length] = new Traktor(znamka, moc, cena, letnik); 

        string[] novaVsebina = new string[listTraktor.Length-1];
        for (int i = 0; i < novaVsebina.Length-1; i++)
        {
            novaVsebina[i] = listTraktor[i].ToString();
        }

        File.WriteAllLines("Agromehanika.txt",novaVsebina , Encoding.UTF8);

    }
```

The array of Tractors is created in the class. Now with this code I want to add a new Tractor to that table and save the values in that txt file. It should basically rewrite all the data in the file plus add the new data that the user has inputed, but i can't seem to understand how to transfer this array to the program itself. Thanks for the help

Comment: My advice is to use a json serialization/deserialization class like NewtonSoft. There are several examples on stackowerflow

Comment: It is for a schoool assignment though and It has to be more or less purely c#.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, I assume that Traktor is a class you created which overrides the ToString method so that it returns the wanted information about the tractor instead of {Namespace}.Traktor.

The first problem I see with your code is the following line:

```
    listTraktor[listTraktor.Length] = new Traktor(znamka, moc, cena, letnik);
```

Note that in C# and many other programming languages, the index of the first element of an array is 0, and because of that the index of the last element of an array is its length - 1.

i.e: An array with 10 elements starts at index 0 and ends at index 9.

Therefore this line of code will result in a IndexOutOfRangeException. To change the value of the last element of an array you should write:

```
listTraktor[listTraktor.Length - 1] = new Traktor(znamka, moc, cena, letnik);
// haven't seen the parameters you pass to Traktor's constructor assigned, make sure you are also passing variables that exist in the context and are assigned
```

The next issue is the initialization of string[] novaVsebina. You are creating a string array that its length is smaller than the listTraktor array by 1. That essentially means you have no way of storing the strings of all the elements in listTraktor because your string array's length is smaller. If you want to store all of the tractors ToString() results in separate array elements, you need to make that string array at the same length of the tractors array.

The last problem is your for loop condition. As I explained previously, the index of the last element of any array in C# is the array's length minus 1. Your condition is: i < listTraktor.Length - 1, which means that when i equals to listTraktor.Length - 1 (which, again- is the index of the last element in your array) the condition will be false and the for loop will exit without storing a value in the last element of the array.
To solve it you need to either make your condition smaller-or-equals to the last index of the array (<=) or remove the - 1 (both will result in the same behaviour, because when i equals listTraktor.Length, it is bigger than the last index by 1, and since listTraktor.Length is not smaller than listTraktor.Length, the condition will be false).

After fixing all of the issues above, your code should work as intended.

Comment: Yes thank you, that made it work, I completely forgot about the indexing of arrays, which starts at 0 and not 1!

Comment: Glad I could help :)